# How to get specific field with condition in list of nested objects with nested lists?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

Is there some way to query in order to get as return all the Prices sum by ID?

For all documents, even if the next document has other IDs?

Data:

```
{"_id":"5c62d9693ec4721d2ab07f72",
       "List1":[{"ID1":"123",
                "List2":[{"Price":10,
                         "Status":"Paid"}, 
                        [{"Price":15,
                        "Status":"Pending"}]]},
                {"ID1":"456",
                "List2":[{"Price":20,
                          "Status":"Paid"}]}]}
```

Expected return:

"ID1": "123"
"Total": 10

"ID1":"456",
"Total": 20

Comment: is your 2nd entry in List1.List2 really a list or an object?

Comment: Answer found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671971/is-there-a-way-to-return-specific-nested-fields-from-a-query-in-mongodb/54724862#54724862.