# Is there a way to return specific nested fields from a query in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, embedded-documents

Is there a way to get the **amount of money paid per Sport's category**?
It can't be restricted only to "John," but in all collection documents.

**Expected query return** for data provided:

```
{
  {"Fight":   [100,95] },
  {"Running": [50]     }
}
```

**Example of data:**

```
{"_id":"5z621578b0ce483b9866fb1f",
 "Name":"John",
 "Sports":[
           {"Category":"Fight",
            "Billing":[
                       {"Month":"Jan",
                        "Status":"Paid",
                        "Price":100},
                      {"Month":"Feb",
                       "Status":"Not Paid",
                       "Price":125}, 
                      {"Month":"Mar",
                       "Status":"Paid",
                       "Price":95}      
                      ]
           },

          {"Category":"Running",
           "Billing":[
                      {"Month":"Jan",
                       "Status":"Not Paid",
                       "Price":200}, 
                      {"Month":"Feb",
                       "Status":"Paid",
                       "Price":50}  
                     ]
          }
      ]
}
```

In other words: I need to compare the **billing Status** inside every nested object and **check if it's"Paid"**, then if true, add the  **respective billing object Price** to the **respective Sport's Category** array.

For all documents in the collection, with multiple sport's categories and multiple billing's month. But always same nested structure.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you'll want to do an aggregation -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As willis said in his comment, you will want to use aggreagation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

---

The following aggregation will give you the data that you are looking for (replace billings with the actual name of your collection):

```
db.billings.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$Sports'},
    { $unwind: '$Sports.Billing'},
    { $match: { 'Sports.Billing.Status': 'Paid' } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$Sports.Category',
            Category: {$first: '$Sports.Category'},
            Prices: { $push: '$Sports.Billing.Price' }
        }
    },
    { $project: {_id: 0} }
]);
```

The result of this aggregation will look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Category" : "Running",
        "Prices" : [ 
            50.0
        ]
    },
    {
        "Category" : "Fight",
        "Prices" : [ 
            100.0, 
            95.0
        ]
    }
]
```

---

The exact format that you requested in your question is a bit abnormal; in my opinion, I think it would be better to keep it in the form the aggregation above outputs.  But if you want it in a form like the one in your question, the aggregation is a bit more complex:

```
db.billings.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$Sports'},
    { $unwind: '$Sports.Billing'},
    { $match: { 'Sports.Billing.Status': 'Paid' } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$Sports.Category',
            Prices: { $push: '$Sports.Billing.Price' }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: 0,
            Sports: { $push: { Category: '$_id', Prices: '$Prices' } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Sports: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    '$map': {
                        'input': '$Sports',
                        'as': 'el',
                        'in': {
                            'k': '$$el.Category',
                            'v': '$$el.Prices'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$Sports'} }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jcarter ! Brilliant